# How do I open a website in browser through JAVA without having the browser open a new tab

Tags: java

**Introduction**

I am making a proxy server in java. Whenever the user enters an unknown host (URL) in the browser, the proxy server handles `UnknownHostException` by executing the code below:

```
try {
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start http://www.mysite.com/unknownhosterror.htm"); 
    }
    catch(IOException io) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

What these lines of code do is to display an html file containing "This page could
 not be displayed." whenever the user entered a non-existing URL.

**Problem**

The code above opens a new tab and displays the content of www.mysite.com/unknownhosterror.htm. What I want is to redirect to it.

For example, I wrote www.nosuchsite.com in the URL bar. Suppose there is no such site, it will automatically redirect to www.mysite.com/unknownhosterror.htm and display "This page could not be displayed.".

How can I do this?

*EDIT* NOTE: I do not use `Servlet`.

Comment: The behaviour depends on browser and browser settings. You cannot do it without browser-specific coding.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you mean but if you indeed have a proxy server, they you should be able to issue a [301 redirect](http://www.skillipedia.com/howto.hm?rid=297) back to the browser when the proxy server detects the `UnknownHostException`.

In the response to the browser, you need to add something like the following lines to the header of your response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.mysite.com/unknownhosterror.htm
```

How to add that to your headers depends highly on how you are handling the requests.  If you show a little bit of your proxy handler code, I can provide more information.